# CUDA SDK compilation error

Tags: linux, cuda, nvidia

I am in the process of setting up a CUDA workstation.

Platform specs:
Intel Core 2 Duo,
Nvidia GTX 280,
Fedora 10,
GCC version 4.3.2

I have installed the developer driver, toolkit, and the SDK. 
When I try to compile the SDK example code I get the following errors:

```
make[1]: *** [obj/i386/release/cutil.cpp.o] Error 1

make: *** [lib/libcutil.so] Error 2
```

I think this means that I am missing a library file but I'm not sure.

Comment: No, that most likely means there is some error in cutil.cpp and it can't be compiled.  Please include the compiler errors which should be immediately before the lines you posted.

Comment: The only other messages I see are warnings that all say "warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type". This is normal from what I've observed on other systems.

Comment: You either have `-Werror` defined (which causes a warning to be treated as an error) or you are missing an actual error.  Try redirecting output to a file (`make 2>&1 | tee make.log`) and then go through make.log to verify you haven't missed an error.

Comment: Thanks, I won't be back in the lab until Monday. I will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Looks like the Cuda toolkit was not installed correctly. Maybe I made an amateur mistake of not being SU.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to build the cutil library by yourself ..
Inside the SDK folder, browse into the 'common" folder and type make to build the cutil files!

Comment: OK, I will give it a try Monday when I'm back in the lab.